# Permission Denied when submitting multiple jobs through a loop

Tags: python, os.system

I'm trying to create and submit multiple jobs to gaussian using python code. **When I run this code:**

```
for iframe in mols_xyz.trajectory:
    mol_ind = iframe.frame + 1
    g16_input = input_dir / f'{mol_base}_{mol_ind}.sh'
    with g16_input.open('w') as fn:
        fn.write('#!/bin/sh -l\n')
        fn.write('\n')
        fn.write('#$ -pe omp 8\n')
        fn.write('#$ -P porcogrp\n')
        fn.write('#$ -l h_rt=24:00:00\n')
        fn.write('#$ -j y\n')
        fn.write('\n')
        fn.write('module load gaussian/16.A.03\n')
        fn.write('\n')
        fn.write(f'HOMEFOL={str(input_dir)}\n')
        fn.write(f'INPUTFILE={str(input_dir)}/{mol_base}_{mol_ind}.com\n')
        fn.write(f'OUTFILE={str(input_dir)}/{mol_base}_{mol_ind}.log\n')
        fn.write('\n')
        fn.write('SCRATCHDIR=/scratch/$USER/$JOB_ID\n')
        fn.write('mkdir -p $SCRATCHDIR\n')
        fn.write('cd $SCRATCHDIR\n')
        fn.write('g16 $HOMEFOL/$INPUTFILE > $HOMEFOL/$OUTFILE')

        os.system(qsub g16_input)
```

**The result is:**

```
[zpowers@scc1 Test]$ python gaussian_Input.py
  File "gaussian_Input.py", line 59
    os.system(qsub g16_input)
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Really stuck here, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show us a `ls -al` listing of your folder and the user you run thsi as.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around your system call. The command is a string:

`os.system('qsub g16_input')`

See docs: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.system

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. When I try that I get: Unable to read script file because of error: error opening g16_input: No such file or directory. When I put the quotes on just the 'qsub' it says: TypeError: must be str, not PosixPath. When I try g16_input.name it says: Unable to run job: job rejected: no script in your request.
Exiting.

Comment: If `g16_input` isn't in your current directory or on your $PATH you'll have to provide the full path. Where is `g16_input` located on your filesystem relative to where you're running the script?

Comment: Hey I figured out the problem. My os.system(qsub g16_input)  should not have been indented. I removed the indent and it worked. Thanks for your help. Sorry I'm such a noob.